# Cygwin .sh file run as Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, shell, cygwin

Having issues getting this shell script to run in windows task scheduler.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script to ping the VPN server for testing

RESULT=$(ping 192.168.1.252 | grep "Lost" | awk {' print $10 '})
LOG=/home/admin/results.txt

if [ "$RESULT" -gt 0 ];then

    echo "VPN 192.168.1.252 NOT pinging" >> $LOG
else

echo "VPN Online"

fi
```

When I run it in cygwin, it runs with no issue, but when I attempt to run it from command prompt, I get the following:

C:\cygwin64\bin>bash test.sh
test.sh: line 4: grep: command not found

test.sh: line 4: awk: command not found

test.sh: line 7: [: : integer expression expected

My question is, how do I get it to run with bash instead so that it actually knows the grep and awk commands?

In Windows Scheduler, I have Action: Start A Program
Details: C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe
Argument: test.sh
Start in: C:\cygwin64\bin

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 10):

I figured it out.

In the Windows Task Scheduler, I had to pass:

Program/script: C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe

Add arguments: -c -l test.sh

Start in: C:\cygwin64\bin

Comment: Hi there, Maybe you could help me out with a similar issue I had [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21517909/schedule-running-a-bash-shell-script-in-windows)

Comment: More specifically, How do I add arguments in the task scheduler? I have the following in my run as `C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -l /cygdrive/c/path/where/the/file/is/filename.sh` And I have Start in: `C:\cygwin\bin`

Answer (score 0):

In correction to what Jimmy found:

> Add arguments: -c -l "c:/FileFolder/test.sh"

You don't need the Start in argument anymore.

Answer (score 0):

For the longest time I was experiencing the same issue as the OP: `command not found` errors when trying to run a shell script from Task Scheduler or the Command Prompt, despite the fact that running the same script from a Cygwin terminal worked fine.

After some more research I eventually realised that the reason was because my usual Bash PATH `~/.bashprofile` wasn't being loaded, and that I needed to use Windows' Environment Variables window to add `C:\cygin64\bin` to my PATH environment variable (system or user, it doesn't really matter). This directory contains common system executables like `grep` and `awk`, which is why Bash is unable to locate them until the path is added to Windows' PATH.

[image]