# running shell script with windows task scheduler

Tags: windows, shell, scheduled-tasks

I currenty have a simple shell script that I created for a linux machine to be run using cron, but now I want to be able to run the file using windows task scheduler. I have tried to get it to work using cron for cygwin, but even after running cron-config successfully and ensuring that the shell script can be executed successfully, for some reason the cron task simply wasn't executing. So I decided to give in and use the windows task scheduler. In order to do this, I looked at the following posts about the issue:

[Cgywin .sh file run as Windows Task Scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285809/cgywin-sh-file-run-as-windows-task-scheduler)

http://www.davidjnice.com/cygwin_scheduled_tasks.html

in my case, the entry in the "actions" tab of the new task looks like this:

program/script: `c:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe`

arguments: `-l -c "/cygdrive/c/users/paul/bitcoinbot/download_all_data.sh >> cygdrive/c/users/paul/bitcoinbot/logfile.log 2>&1"`

start in: `c:\cygwin64\bin`

Notice that I redirected the output of the shell script to a log file, so that I should be able to see there whether the program run. Other than that, I simply edited the "trigger" tab to run the task daily, and set the time to a couple of minutes in the fture to see whether it ran successfully.

Alas, when I look at the detailed event history for the task, nothing changes when the trigger time passes. And when I manually "run" the task, the event history seems to add a few different events, but the task is completed within seconds, whereas this task should take over an hour (and it does when the shell script is executed directly from the terminal). And when I look for the log file that should have been created, there is nothing.

Does anyone have any idea what might be the issue here? How can I get my task to run properly at the trigger time, and how can I make sure it does so?

Best,

Paul

EDIT:
here are the pictures showing event history, as per Ken White's request.
[image]
Please ignore the fact that it says there are 24 events. These are from multiple separate runs of the task. The events shown here are a complete list of the events triggered by a single run.

EDIT 2:
Regarding my attempts to get cron to work, I have run into the following problem when I try to start the cron service using cygrunsrv. First of all, I tried to start cron by typing

`cygrunsrv -I cron -p /usr/sbin/cron.exe -a -D`

Now when I type

`$cygrunsrv -Q cron`
Service: cron
Current State: stopped
Command: /usr/bin/cron.exe

Now, I tried to start the cron service by typing

`cygrunsrv -S cron`
Cygrunsrv: Error starting a service: QueryServiceStatus: Win32 error 1062:
The service has not been started.

Does anyone hae any idea what this error means? I tried googling it, but couldn't find any answers.

Comment: *the event history seems to add a few different events, but I cannot tell what any of them mean*. It would seem to me that it would be a good idea to include them in your post; because *you* don't know what they mean doesn't mean that people here won't, and there's probably useful information there. Without more details, you're just asking for speculation about the many things that could be an issue, and that's too broad for this site.

Comment: Hi Ken, you are right. I have edited my post to show the output of the event history. As you can see, the task appears to be executing, but this cannot be right because it should take much longer. So really there are two distict questions here: why is the task not being triggered? and, why is it not running properly when I run it manually? But I think both of these questions could be answered more definitively if there were some way of seeing the error stream and output of my command.

Comment: Cygwin cron is supposed to work. I would try tor reproduce the problem with a very simple cron task using only commands which are internal to the shell (for example, one running only the command `echo test >/cygdrive/tmp/ctmp.txt` (of course you have to create c:/tmp if it does not exist yet)), and if this really doesn't work, put a question on this on the Cygwin mailing list.

Comment: it appears that even simple commands like this are not working for me. I will post on the cygwin mailing list and get back with the answer.